# Short Puzzle: Graphic Painting

Tags: pattern, visual, letter-sequence, time

[image]

The artist in the market is giving this painting for free (the last one on his rack). I asked him if I can take it but he replied "Why should I give it to you?" The frame could be useful but I dont want to tell him that so I ask him why should he give it for free. He answered "because I miss to paint something into it". It looks like straight edge drawing to me but I'm curious so I asked him what is missing in his painting. He told me that I can take it if I figured it out. I offer to buy it if he would tell me but he just refused while people are now gathering around the painting. What is missing?

Comment: I suggest adding a hint! I've been thinking about this: rot13(Pbhyq vg or gung zbfg bs gur qenja yvarf naq neebjf pbhyq or pbzovarq gb sbezf Kf. Fb vs jr pbzovar nyy bs gurz, jr trg na K gung vf zvffvat n yvar be neebj, fbzrubj?)

Comment: @PaulKaram-Znlor vs lbh vtaber gur fgbel naq whfg ybbx ng vg lbh'yy svther vg bhg.

Comment: Is it related to some rot13(gvzrfgnzc sbe rnpu K)? @TSLF

Comment: @SamRoy-Whfg gur fgvyy cerfrag, fcngvnyyl qvfgbegrq.

Comment: I am still curious about this!

Answer (score 12):

I think the painting is meant to portray:

> Four dimensions - because that appears to be the name of the painting.

But it is missing:

> One of the dimensions. Possibly depth, or the 'fourth' dimension'.

My reasoning:

> The commonly recognised three dimensions are height, width and depth. The fourth dimension is considered to be either the concept of *time* in physics; but in geometry it can be the direction of movement of the 3-dimensional object. The painting appears to have axes for *height* and *width* with marks to denote some kind of scale. The diagonal line in the middle of the painting has *arrows* instead of scale markings. Perhaps this denotes *time* (because time only travels in one direction), in which case the painting lacks *depth*. Or perhaps it is meant to denote depth, in which case it is time that is missing.

It also occurs to me that:

> The action of taking the painting away would technically add the fourth dimension of *movement* to the existing three, so maybe that is why the artist is inviting people to take it away?

Comment: Depth can be represented by the thickness or layers of the paint. It looks like he ought to portray the 4 dimensions  (4Xs) using the "4th dimension" or time.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no art critic, but I'd still say

> the painting lacks depth.

The painter missed to paint something into it, because

> he wants to depict a nice projection of the 4-dimensional coordinate axes, but that takes 3 dimensions, so his paintbrush literally misses when he tries to paint outside the plane of the canvas.

Maybe :-)

Answer (score 3):

The painting is missing:

> the artist's signature, so it is obviously a forgery, hence the price tag.

Answer (score 2):

The painting is missing

> a Time axis.

It's clearly titled.

> It has 4 Xs but only three axes.
>  Read both aloud, enjoy the verbal pununciation, realize "4 Xs" does not equal "3 axes" and tell the painter he needs one axis more (not only for this reason but because, obviously, the titular 4th Dimension needs a 4th axis to be represented on a graph).  The missing axis must be *the* 4th dimension one for Time.

Take your painting home and enjoy the new frame.

Comment: It is about time or 4th dimension

Comment: @TSLF I don't exactly understand your comment. My answer *is* about time or the 4th dimension; what is your comment supposed to tell me?

Comment: The painting is just 2D with 3 arrows that looks like axes. The artist maybe just portraying  space by using time elements. The artist just missed something to paint and maybe there would be no free frame if  he correctly included it to the painting.

Comment: Well. Obviously this is too esoteric for me. :)

Comment: i thought of it as a short puzzle but the "aha" went that illusive

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

> the arrows on the diagonal axis (not the last one) should be replaced with strokes to represent intervals.

And:

> thanks to @Bass, the picture lacks depth, and therefore the intervals on the diagonal axis should be of increasing distance from the origin.

Comment: count the letters

Answer (score 0):

I've got a feeling that the image should have been drawn like this:

> [image: Complete Image with missing item]

Reasoning:

> Each X represents a vector. Since this is a 2D plan, a vector that is perpenduclar to our plan should be represented with a circle that contains a point, or a circle that contains an X (point means the vector is pointing from the screen to you, X means the vector is pointing from you to the screen.)

Another possible solution is:

> [image: Another Solution]

Comment: It is just 4th dimension (time).  What's the first thing that you can think of?

Comment: Normally I'd think of a clock (digital or analog), date, seconds, minutes, stuff like that... @TSLF